# AWS AMI label not recognized in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, agent

I am trying to setup an AWS AMI agent in Jenkins via the EC2 plugin.  I add a label to the AMI in the cloud/node configuration and add the agent to my jenkinsfile:

`agent {label 'agent'}`

But when I try to run the job, it gets hung up looking for the agent and indicates "‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘agent'."  Any suggestion on how to get Jenkins to recognize the AMI agent label?  Also, I have tested the AWS and AMI connections and they pass just fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Jenkins -> [Controller name] -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Clouds
or just add to the URL "https://YOURDOMAINOFJENKINS/manage/configureClouds/".

Check if you have the agent with the label "agent". Check not the description, check the "Labels" under this agent settings. Click on Check AMI to verify that your Jenkins can see and have the right configuration to pull the AMI.

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins is an open source automation server. It helps automate the parts of software development related to building, testing, and deploying, facilitating continuous integration and continuous delivery